# Sorting - Bubble/Selection

Tags: c++, sorting

I use Dev-C++.The program crashes everytime I use my sorting functions.None of the sorts work :|

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
void bsort(char * items,int length)
{
     bool ex = true;
     for(int a = 0;a < length;a++)
     {
             cout<<"Exchange";
         if(ex == false) break;
         ex = false;
         for(int b = 0;b >=  (length-1);b++)
         {

             if(items[b] < items[b+1])
             {
                  ex = true;
                  items[b] ^= items[b+1];
                  items[b+1] ^= items[b];
                  items[b] ^= items[b+1];    

             }                
         }        
     }        
     cout<<items;  
}
void sort(char * items,int count)
{
    register int a,b;
    register char t;

    for(a = 1;a < count;++a)
    {
          for(b = count-1; b >= a;--b)
          {
              if(items[b-1] > items[b])
              {
                   cout<<"Exchange";
                   t = items[b-1];
                   items[b-1] = items[b];
                   items[b] = t;              
              }      
          }      
    }    
}
void xselect(char * items,int count)
{
          char c = items[0];
          for(int a = 1;a < count;a++)
          {
              if(c > items[a])        
              {
                   c ^= items[a];
                   items[a] ^= c;
                   c ^= items[a];    
              }
          }
          cout<<items;
}
int main ()
{
    char * p = "I am awesome";
    xselect(p,strlen(p));
    cout<<p;
    return cin.get();
}
```

What is going wrong?

Edit:The algorithim may be wrong but what is causing the program to crash?I get "app.exe has stopped working..."

Comment: I think the condition in your nested loop is wrong.

Comment: And why are you using `register` variable?

Comment: And why do you use xor for swapping? In most cases that's slower than using the idiomatic temporary variable, and in any case more obscure.

Comment: Avoiding temporary variables aren't better?Ofc, its slower because temp var will just have 3 assignment instructions whereas XOR will have 3 + 3 instructions to be carried out.But I did not know which one to choose "avoid temp variable or use temp variable".Help me choose :)

Comment: Since I few of the variables are continuously used I made them as register variables.Would the compiler know better than me and do better optimizations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your function you have:

```
    char * p = "I am awesome";
```

where "I am awesome" is a const char*. During the sorting you are trying to mutate that, which is as far as I'm aware undefined behaviour.

instead allocate a char* first and fill it with the desired string.

Or better yet since you are working in C++ try using std::string which takes care of most of the stringhandling.

Ps: In the future please try identifying which section of the code is relevant and post that snippet instead of a link. Further, more detailed information on when it crashes (line number for example) can help yourself and others in finding the issue.

Comment: Also, you can use an array instead of pointer due to the problem Stratege has mentioned.  char p[] = "I am awesome";

Comment: Oh yea, never noticed it :P Thanks

Answer (score 1):

void bsort : what you did => for(int b = 0;b >=  (length-1);b++)

what you need to did => for(int b = 0;b <  length;b++)

void sort : it works fine at my pc.

void xselect : `void xselect(string items,int count){
    for(int i=0;i<count-1;i++)
    {
          char c = items[i];
          for(int a = i+1;a < count;a++)
          {
              if(c > items[a])

              {
                   cout<<c<<items[a]<<endl;
                   c ^= items[a];
                   items[a] ^= c;
                   c ^= items[a];
                   items[i]=c;
                   cout<<c<<items[a]<<endl;
              }
          }
    }
          cout<<items;
    }`

Comment: I can't see any difference :|